# Minecraft Mod to create files and folders

Tags: file-io, minecraft

I'm currently creating a mod for Minecraft.  It's another computer mod and I need it to store all the files and folders the user creates on the computer into the computers own personal folder.  For each instance of a computer a folder with that computers number will be created and that is the folder where all of the files and folders inside of that specific computer will be loacated for instance: say that the folders were to be in the directory C:/mc/mods then the first computer would have the folder C:/mc/mods/1 the second C:/mc/mods/2 and so on just like computercraft does.  My problem is that despite many attempts and much research I have been able to create neither the folders nor the files.  Here is what my code looks like upon the block being placed.

```
File file = new File("C:/mc/mods");
if (file.isDirectory() == false) {
    file.mkdir();
}
String s = "C:/mc/mods/1";
file = new File(s);
int iii = 2;
while (file.isDirectory()) {
    String ss = s.substring(0,s.length() - 1);
    s = ss + iii;
    file = new File(s);
    iii += 1;
}
file.mkdir();
file = new File("C:/mc/mods/locs.txt");
try {
file.createNewFile();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
try {
PrintWriter outp = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C:/mc/mods/locs.txt",true)));
outp.println(x + "," + y + "," + z + "," + Integer.toString(iii - 1));
outp.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

It basically just makes sure I have the main folder created, then it creates a subfolder for the specific computer and in the main folder it logs the exact position and number of that computer.  If anyone could help me out with figuring out how to do this correctly that would be great thanks.  Also I'm pretty new to java so sorry about all of the bad performance coding that I'm slowly fixing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post some more information about your problem? Are you getting any stack trace errors showing up in the console?

Comment: Thanks for the welcome.  When I run this (using Feed The Beast) it loads the mod perfectly well and even lets me place the block without error.  The problem is that as I said when I place the block it's supposed to create the folders/files and it doesn't.  Other then that the mod works fine.

Comment: @user2362964 - Please read the "welcome" comment again.  If you want help (as distinct from guesses) you need to show us the stacktraces for the errors you are getting.  This is Java 101 stuff ... using the stacktrace to diagnose errors.  And `System.out.println(e);` is NOT how you print a stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are attempting to write at the root ("C:/") without administrator permission. Try basing your file directory off of Minecraft.getWorkingDirectory (I do not remember the exact method).

It's impossible to know for sure as you have not provided any sort of log, but I hope this works.